# Django form.is_valid() is False, but not hitting the else statement?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I am working on something that should be pretty simple, but running into a very odd form issue.

```
@csrf_protect
def employee_create(request, company_id):

    template_name = 'business/employee-create.html'
    data = dict()
    company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        employee_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if employee_form.is_valid():
            logger.debug('Valid')
            emp = employee_form.save(commit=False)
            emp.company = venue
            emp.user = request.user
            emp.save()
            return redirect('comp_detail', company_id=company_id)
        else:
            logger.debug('Error')

    else:
        employee_form = EmployeeForm()
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string(
            template_name,
            {'form': employee_form, 'company_id': company.id},
            request=request,
        )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The `GET` request is just a popup bootstrap form. But my odd situation is happening in the `POST` request. I am sending an invalid form that is completely empty(in the form modal I get djangos built in form errors popping up) , but the `else` statement never gets hit, that is supposed to print `Error` in my django logger.

The form is invalid, but is also not invalid? There has to be something that I am missing here??

Thanks in advance for anyone that takes a glance!

Comment: `logger.debug` will not always log the item. It depends on the logging level of the logger.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that actually!

Comment: perhaps you can use `logger.error` very likely this is a log level that will be logged by the logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger is usually set to a certain *log level*. This means that, depending on the level, some logging may not be logged. The [log levels [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) are in ascending order: `NOTSET`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`.

The root logger is normally created with `WARNING` as threshold, so `INFO`, `DEBUG` and `NOTSET` will *not* be logged.

You can alter the threshold value, or you can log the messages with a higher level:

```
if employee_form.is_valid():
    logger.error('Valid')
    # …
else:
    logger.error('Error')
```